# Через что можно вывести json картинок, с титулками и ссылками для слайдера, в wordpress rest-api?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Здравствуйте, нужно сделать слайдер в приложении, сервер которого это wordpress (а точнее его апи). Kак можно вывести с вордпреса json, в котором будет массив картинок, а также титулок и ссылок к ним.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо в библиотеке дать требуемому массиву картинок какое-то общее описание. Для теста я добавил слово `Mountains` одной картинке в title

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

другой в description.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом воспользовался поиском по медиафайлам:

http://test.kagg.eu/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?search=Mountains

Результат можно посмотреть по ссылке выше или на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]